# Android SQLite query all rows and bind it to a listview

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hi I am following the [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_SQLite_Database_Tutorial#The_Query_Handler_Method) on this site  to create a database. However, I can't wrap my mind around how to query all rows and bind it to a list view. Here's my code to find a *specific* entry

```
 public Entry findEntry(String entryName) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ENTRY + " WHERE " + ENTRY_NAME + " =  \"" + entryName + "\"";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Entry entry = new Entry();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        entry.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        entry.setEntryName(cursor.getString(1));
        entry.setEntryDesc(cursor.getString(2));
        entry.setEntryTime(cursor.getString(3));
        entry.setEntryDate(cursor.getString(4));
        entry.setEntryLocation(cursor.getString(5));
        entry.setImgUrI(cursor.getString(6));
    } else{
        entry = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return entry;
}
```

However I want to `SELECT * FROM TABLE_ENTRY` and return a list of the entry names and load it into a listview, but i have no idea how.

Comment: check `Custom adapter` with `listview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a xml file for each row of the `ListView`. Use as many `TextView` you want to display as many instance variable information you would like from the `Entry` class.

entry_list_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entryListEntryIDTextView"
        android:textSize="@dimen/page_entry_size"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
```

Then create a Custom Adapter :

```
public class EntryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {

    Context ctx;
    List<Entry> entryList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public AccountListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Entry> entryList) {
        super(context, R.layout.entry_list_row, entryList);
        ctx = context;
        accountList = accList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            Account account = accountList.get(position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_list_row, parent, false);

            TextView entryListEntryIDTextView =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.entryListEntryIDTextView);
            entryListEntryIDTextView.setText(entry.getID());
            //Do this for all other TextViews. For all the information you want to show up
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And then in the Activity/Fragment :

```
ArrayList<Entry> entryList = database.getAllEntries(); //Use the object reference name to your data access class, and the appropriate method name.

ListView entryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.entryListView); //Or whatever you have named the ListView in the xml file of the activity

entryListView.setAdapter(new EntryListAdapter(getActivity(), entryList));
```